# Why is str.contains() not returning the correct results?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = pd.Series(['57 Freeport Crescent NE',  '890 4 Avenue SW'])
```

And I have the following dictionary in which I joined together the keys and values since I am interested in searching all of them through my list

```
direction = {
        '^Northwest$': '$NW^',
        '^Northeast$': '$NE^',
        '^Southeast$': '$SE^',
        '^Southwest$': '$SW^',
        '^North$': '$N^',
        '^East$': '$E^',
        "^South$": '$S^',
        "^West$": "$W^"}

all_direction = direction.keys() | direction.values()
all_direction = '|'.join(all_direction)
```

My question is why doesn't `lst.str.contains(all_direction, case = False)` return both False, but instead of returning both True since they contain NE and SW?

Comment: What's `$NW^` ? Do you mean `^NW$` ?

Comment: What is this line doing `all_direction = direction.keys() | direction.values()`?

Comment: That is just to get the dictionary items since I am trying to match them in my series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it might be because of the symbols.

Is it necessary to have `$`, `^`?

because without those symbols I believe the code would work.

Comment: The symbols are for matching the entire string instead of a substring, ^ is for starts with and $ is for ends with.

Comment: If you're trying to use regex you probably should use `re` package

Comment: Or instead of using `$NE^` you could use `^NE|NE$`. this would work also.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because `pd.Series(['57 Freeport Crescent NE',  '890 4 Avenue SW'])` results in:

output:

```
0    57 Freeport Crescent NE
1            890 4 Avenue SW
dtype: object
```

I don't have much experience using this but it seems that you can use this as a list. SW and NE will not be in that list because in each index there is a full string instead of separate. I don't know if this answers your question though...

Answer (score 1):

After you join your dictionary keys and values, you'll get a string.

```
all_direction = '^Southeast$|$NE^|$SW^|$N^|$S^|$W^|^East$|^Northeast$|$SE^|$NW^|^South$|$E^|^Southwest$|^North$|^West$|^Northwest$'
```

lst.str.contains(all_direction) will check if the string 'all_direction' is present in the list 'lst'.

```
lst = 0    57 Freeport Crescent NE
      1    890 4 Avenue SW

lst.str.contains(all_direction, case = False)
0    False
1    False
dtype: bool
```

lst doesn't contain the string all_direction. That's why it's returning False.

```
lst.str.contains('e', case=False)
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

All the elements of lst contain the letter 'e'.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking the whole regex pattern, I've taken the minimum which can match.
Here, when try searching '$NE^' in the pandas series, It is returning None, hence resulting in False.

```py
lst.str.contains('$NE^', case = False)

0    False
1    False
dtype: bool
```

This is because the regex expression you have written is incorrect It should have been **'^NE$'** i.e. starts with 'NE' and ends with 'NE' but to match the first row your expression should be **'NE$'** which means to end with NE while ignoring the case.

```py
lst.str.contains('NE$', case = False) 

0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```